# Is there a possibility to only write in an image from c# client and read from python server in the same time?

Tags: c#, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, read-write

I am currently reading from  file like this in python

python server side:

```
from PIL import Image

img1 = Image.open(
        'p1.png')

img1 = img1.resize((224,224))
img1 = img1.convert('RGB')
```

C# client side:

```
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("incomplete.png", bytes);
    if (File.Exists(@"p.png")) 
    {
        File.Delete(@"p.png");
    }
    File.Move(@"incomplete.png", @"p.png");
```

The issue is that i need to write and to read from that png almost in the same time and  it throws from time to time errors  that c# client can not access the file ***IOException: Sharing violation on path***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having multiple programs reading and writing files at the same time is a recipe for disaster. I would encourage you to take a step back and re-consider your design...

In the mean time, the issues are probably caused by the C# program writing in the file while Python is reading it. One way to avoid these issues is to ensure that the view of the file is always consistent. So, in your C# program, write the file with the name `incomplete.png` and then, in the next line, rename that file as `p.png`. As the `rename` is an atomic operation, the Python file can only *"see"* either the new file or the old file but not a mixture of the two.

Comment: i modified as you proposed but it still gives me the same error. The issue is caused indeed by reading and writing  in the same time but that is the best approach in my case unfortunately. Can you have a look at c# implementation maybe  ypu reffered to something else :).

Comment: Try putting your `Image.open()` in Python in a `try/except` clause and putting that inside a loop, retrying until successful.